# On a particular kind of ideals in Noetherian local rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, localization, cohen-macaulay

Let us call an ideal $I$ of a Noetherian local ring $(R, \mathfrak m)$ special if $\mathfrak m I \ne \mathfrak m ( I : \mathfrak m)$ .

I have the following questions:

(1) Let $I$ be a special ideal in a Noetherian local ring $(R, \mathfrak m)$, then is it true that $I_P (=IR_P)$ is special in $(R_P, PR_P)$ for every prime ideal $P$ of $R$ containing $I$ i.e. for every prime ideal $P \in Ass (R/I)$ ?

(2) Let $I$ be an ideal in a Noetherian ring $R$ such that $I_{\mathfrak m}$ is special in $ R_{\mathfrak m}$ for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak m \in Ass (R/I)$ , then is it  true that $I_P (=IR_P)$ is special in $R_P$ for every prime ideal $P \in Ass (R/I) $ ?

If either of (1) or (2) is not true in general, I would like to know if they are true for some special kind of rings (like say Cohen-Macaulay rings ...)

Note that easily (2) implies (1) .

Some remarks about special ideals : $I$ is special in  $(R, \mathfrak m)$ if and only if $(I: \mathfrak m)\ne (\mathfrak m I :\mathfrak m)$ if and only if $( (I:\mathfrak m)/I ). (\mathfrak m/I \mathfrak m) \ne 0$ if and only if $I \hat R$ is special in $\hat R$ ($ \hat R $ being the completion of $R$ w.r.t. the maximal ideal). Also note that if $I$ is special, then depth $R/I=0$ .

Comment: Just to clarify: is $(I : \mathfrak{m})$ the ideal $\{x \in R : x \mathfrak{m} \subseteq I\}$? And $R$ is assumed commutative?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: yes your definition of the colon ideal is exactly right and yes $R$ is Commutative

Comment: You may want to restrict the set of prime ideals to $V(I)$ or something. For instance, if $R$ is a domain, then after localizing at the zero ideal you lose the specialty of $I$.

Comment: @Youngsu: that is a rather good point ... I definitely don't want to invert elements in $I$ ...

Comment: @Youngsu: your point made me realize that for $I_P$ to be special, depth $(R/I)_P=0$ so $PR_P$ is an associated primes of $(R/I)_P$ , so $P$ has to be an associated prime of $R/I$ ...